# Upload Panel and Timer refreshes page completely :(

Tags: asp.net

I have an updatepanel and a timer.

I want to refresh just my updatepanel but when I put a timer inside updatepanel it doesnt work and when I put it outside my page it does.

What should I do?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updLastAouction" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>


        مزایده شماره : <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbAuctionID"></asp:Label>

       <br/>
       <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        آخرین قیمت پیشنهادی :
        </div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbLastOrderPrice"></asp:Label>

        <div class="lastBidder">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            آخرین پیشنهاد دهنده
            </div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbLastBidder">ندارد</asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="lastBidder" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <div class="font">
            زمان باقی مانده</div>

            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbLeftTime" Text='<%#DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>'></asp:Label>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLastAouction" Text="برای شرکت عضو شوید" 
                        onclick="btnLastAouction_Click"/>
                    </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel><asp:Timer ID="timerLastAouction" runat="server" Interval="1000" 
                        OnTick="timerLastAouction_Tick" />
```

Comment: Why does it have to be inside the update panel?

Comment: because i want to update just update panel not page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Timer is not inside of the `UpdatePanel` it will cause a full postback. You could add an [AsyncPostbackTigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) to the `UpdatePanel`:

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timerLastAouction" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
```

Or you could wrap the Timer Control in a separate `UpdatePanel` to avoid the full page postback.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"
    ID="upTimer">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="timerLastAouction" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timerLastAouction_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: no not working :( i need this, it's very important for this project

Comment: this is true, but my mistake was in codebehind thanks allot bro